# how to remove all characters except for those enclosed by parentheses

Tags: r

Suppose you have a text file like this below

```
I have apples, bananas, ( some pineapples over 4 ), and cherries ( coconuts with happy face :D ) and so on. You may help yourself except for cherries ( they are for my parents sorry ;C ) . I feel like I can run a fruit business.
```

What I aim to do is to erase all characters except for those enclosed by parentheses. Please keep in mind that the characters in a pair of parentheses can be varied ranging from English to other characters but no other punctuations may play a role as enclosing characters: only parentheses can be allowed to do.

I think I should utilize `gsub` but not sure.

This is what I want to have as a result.

```
( some pineapples over 4 ) ( coconuts with happy face :D ) ( they are for my parents sorry ;C )
```

Whether using a way of removing or extracting, I hope to get the result above.

Comment: @Sotos This is not the correct dupe.  If you check the dupe links, it is just extracting the strings

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997730/how-to-remove-all-characters-except-for-those-enclosed-by-parentheses-in-r

Comment: @akrun nah, I thought to leave it there as many "extract from parentheses" searches might lead to this answer

Comment: @Sotos Oh okay, thanks,

Comment: @Sotos I also added another solution based on gsub which was not in the duped one commented

Comment: @akrun nice 1. No idea how that regex works though...

Comment: @Sotos The idea is to match those characters that are inside the brackets and it is skipped allowing only other characters (`.`) to match and replace with blanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by extracting the substring within the brackets and `paste` it together

```
library(stringr)
paste(str_extract_all(str1, "\\([^)]*\\)")[[1]], collapse=' ')
#[1] "( some pineapples over 4 ) ( coconuts with happy face :D ) ( they are for my parents sorry ;C )"
```

---

Or we can use a `gsub` based solution

```
trimws(gsub("\\s+\\([^)]*\\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", "", str1, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "( some pineapples over 4 ) ( coconuts with happy face :D ) ( they are for my parents sorry ;C )"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "I have apples, bananas, ( some pineapples over 4 ), and cherries ( coconuts with happy face :D ) and so on. You may help yourself except for cherries ( they are for my parents sorry ;C ) . I feel like I can run a fruit business."
```

Comment: Thx! Brilliant!